# Pushing image over the page container

Tags: html, css, image

I have a web page that is 960px wide. Inside this page there's a section with an image inside that I want pushed all the way to the right so it's half way outside the page. The attached image below will show you an example of what I would wan this to look like.

I would also like it if the image is in the background so if the browser window is small in width it would just keep covering the image.

Here's a couple sites that has this:

http://cpanel.com/products/

At cpanel you can see the iPad on that page is only half way displayed when the browser window is smaller than image.

Another website with this effect is Doteasy.com here's the URL:

http://www.doteasy.com/

If you scroll down to the middle of their page you will see the Site builder section which includes a screenshot of the software. Their page is 980px wide and you can see that the screenshot is halfway outside the page wrapper.

The image should be 552px widde by 315px high.

[image]

```css
.container {
    width: 960px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: yellow;
}

section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 508px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.image {
    width: 552px;
    height: 315px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Site Example</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
</head>
<body>
    <section>
      <h1>This is the Section</h1>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="image">This would be the image.</div>
        </div>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope you guys are able to help !

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can position absolutely relative to the container like so:

- Add `position: relative;` to the container
- Add absolute positioning to the image `position: absolute; top: 0; right: -276px;` (The right value is half the image width)
- `overflow-x: hidden` on the container will stop the extra half of the image from being visible.

```css
section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 508px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: green;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.image {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -276px;
    width: 552px;
    height: 315px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>This is the Section</h1>
  <div class="container">
    This is the container
    <div class="image">This would be the image.</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks! How do I place the image in the background so the side scroll won't show ?

Comment: @RichardRodgers I've updated the answer, using `overflow-x: hidden` on the container will stop the rest of the image expanding the page width.

Comment: Again, thanks so much for helping me out. If the browser window is big enough I would like to show the entire width of image. Right now I see that even though the browser window is big enough to fit that image it still only showing half of it.

Comment: You can check doteasy.com and scroll down to their Site builder section on on their homepage. You'll see the screenshot image on the right. I am trying to accomplish the same effect.

Comment: @RichardRodgers You can get that effect by moving the `overflow-x: hidden` to the `section` rather than the `.container`. However this will start to  look strange if your window gets less than `960px` (Which is why if you reduce the doteasy site, they use media queries to change the layout of the site below a certain resolution) Simplified example here since you can't resize stackoverflow snippets easily: https://jsfiddle.net/6wgs78tz/1/

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for your help ! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. I added `position: relative` to the .container and section, then `position: absolute` to the image container. You can then use `left: 25%` to adjust how far off screen you would like the image to be. The 25% can be adjusted according to your needs. You can also use px instead of percentages if that works better for your needs.

```css
.container {
    width: 960px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

section {
    width: 100%;
    height: 508px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: relative;
}

.image {
    width: 552px;
    height: 315px;
    background-color: red;
    position: absolute;
    left: -25%; /* -- Adjust this percentage as needed -- */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Site Example</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
</head>
<body>
    <section>
      <h1>This is the Section</h1>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="image">This would be the image.</div>
        </div>
    </section>

</body>
</html>
```